# How many server for my BI project (DW and application)?

Tags: hardware, business-intelligence, pentaho, jasperserver

I'm currently doing my last year internship. My project is to develop a full BI project for a company.

I'll need to take data from several places (flat files, DB, ...) put it in a DW (that I'll create) and make ad-hoc report. I'll certainly use pentaho or jasper.

I'll have a server (physical) for my DW of course.
The question is, can I install the whole BI application on the same server (the ETL, reporting ...) where I put the DW?

If yes shoud I create 2 virtual server on my only physical server or it's useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Whole BI Application on the same server. You can create several folders for each of BI Component such as BI Server, ETL, Reporting, etc. You needn't create 2 virtual server.

Comment: even my DW can be on that?

Comment: Yes, your DW can be on that

Answer (score 1):

You can also include Ctools plugin into BI Server for better GUI purpose. Saiku and CDE is great you can customize the things in CDE very well. Saiku is kind of next level of bi server so it is very well for you joris.